# Images upload in React ,Nodejs changing from localhost to production in deployment

Tags: web-deployment, react-fullstack

In dev mode i stored some photos and i get them buy using img tag with image link as src.
also , the api request from server using server url.

how should i make react use the correct url while using in  deployment site and not "localhost"

```
//api 
const url = "http://localhost:5000"
const exampleRouter= axios.create({
  baseURL: `${url}/recipes/public`,
});


//In React components - img work fine 
<img src={http://localhost:5000/users/${user._id}/avatar`} alt"avatr">
```

its worked perfectly in localhost, now i should deploy to heroku but i dont know how to treat this links ( i have tame many in my project)

I am using in React as FE and Node as BE with (using Express libary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is frontend code

```
const l = window.location;
const url=`${l.protocol}//${l.host}:${l.port}`;
```

should do the trick.
Also, relative paths are a thing.

Comment: window.location.host return me the client host while i need the server port, do u know how ot get it?

Comment: window.location.port (updated the answer)

Comment: if you get the resources from some other server, you need to habe dev and prod configurations of course.